# Network Theory > Dependent Source | The answer is 84W but how come it is 84W if V0 only is coming 17V

Tags: network

[image]

If I solve this question using KCL then take 5 + V0 at position b then By KCL (5 + V0)/1 + (5 + V0 - 2V0)/2 + 1 = 0. Solving this will give V0 = 17V.  Why is power 84W?

Comment: The question asks for the power supplied by the dependent source only, not the total power in the 1 ohm resistor.

Comment: @RussellH Yes but to find power supply in dependent source we need the voltage in 1 Ohm resistor then the voltage of 2V0 will be 34V so if i calculate power P= 34^2/2 it will be 578W but not 84W.

Comment: But Vo is -7V not +17V

Comment: Check the currents’  directions in your calculations.

Comment: I agree with G36, \$V_0=-7V\$. I also agree with RussellH, this error is likely due to some current direction conflict with [passive sign convention](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Electric_Circuit_Analysis/Passive_Sign_Convention).

Answer (score -1):

According to my calculations, the currents and voltages in the network, respecting the directions of the digraph, are these:

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEt7Sl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>